# Computer behaving erratically at or after startup

Tags: ubuntu, boot

For almost a two weeks now, my desktop has been behaving very strangely and I can't find the cause.
After startup, the screen will get blurry lines and all the other peripherals will freeze and become unusable (mouse, keyboard and any other connected device.) Sometimes, it won't reboot properly but only after multiple attempts. Also at times, it will get stuck in the middle of the boot. The ubuntu indicator that it is starting will stop moving.

Screenshort of the screen bellow:
[image]

But then today, I had it. At startup exactly, instead of a normal boot followed by the screen like above, all I could see was a screen full of zeros.
Screenshot bellow:

[image]

What could be the cause of this and how do I get rid of it?

Computer is running Ubuntu 14.04, 4GB memory, Intel dual core processor.

**P.S.** If am posting to wrong site, kindly redirect to the proper site.

Comment: Looks more like it. The question, what part of the computer can be the source of this?

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply. I have changed the monitor but nothing happened. In case I come up with something, I shall update the question accordingly. I will changing different devices and see which on is the culprit.